# Retrieving specific matches from a list in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/paulc/Documents/Medium Football')
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


base_url = 'https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup'

option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/paulc/Documents/Medium Football/chromedriver.exe",options=option)
driver.get(base_url)
links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")]
```

this code retrieves all the href links on this page. I want to search the links list and return only the matches that contain 'https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a'

[image]

however I get the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
using

```
   import re

[x for x in links if x.startswith('https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a')]
```

help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Evidently, some of the `<a>` tags you grabbed do not have `href` attributes.  `<a>` tags can also be used to create bookmarks in an HTML, so that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is filtering to grab the right links

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for u in soup.select('a[class="gatracking"]'):
    link = 'https://www.sportingindex.com' + u.get('href')

    if '-v-' in link:
        print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.24fdf8f5-b69b-4341-b6b4-d27605f7f7fd/spain-v-germany
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.c9bdf787-791a-47e0-b77c-a2d4cf567bfd/cameroon-v-serbia
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.5eddaa44-666b-47dc-8a0f-4ac758de00dc/south-korea-v-ghana
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.70cefd39-60f7-415e-9cb5-7a56acd403d6/brazil-v-switzerland
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.7fe0285e-366f-4f3c-b77f-4c96077a6c71/portugal-v-uruguay
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.dd7a995d-7478-45f8-af27-9f234d37cc76/ecuador-v-senegal
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.92232207-0f1e-4bb1-bacd-1332ef6b9007/netherlands-v-qatar
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.b913620e-69c7-4606-a153-7b48589b7c94/iran-v-usa
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.7a4a18fb-d4ee-4880-849f-f1afdea33cd5/wales-v-england
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.20c098b4-4e97-4fd1-97b0-f42d84424361/australia-v-denmark
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.5a7476e2-8d35-4a8e-8065-b4339e79f395/tunisia-v-france
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.8a869f02-9dd0-49c5-91bd-209ee224fc2a/poland-v-argentina
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.6379b787-f246-4ba4-a896-28a97396d02f/saudi-arabia-v-mexico
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.52737cfd-da19-42dd-b15b-c16c3e8e9a86/canada-v-morocco
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.168fab1f-8360-4e87-ba84-bfbd11a4a207/croatia-v-belgium
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.9fb541f0-43a4-409c-8e54-e34a43965714/costa-rica-v-germany
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.7379c8a7-ab5d-4653-b487-22bf7ff8eefe/japan-v-spain
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.e7e4c6be-98b7-4258-ba40-74c54a790fe1/ghana-v-uruguay
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.e4c18c81-565e-47ce-b08d-9aed62c88a5d/south-korea-v-portugal
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.18f44028-e23d-48d4-970b-e75c164589bd/cameroon-v-brazil
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.526f9b1b-6d95-4f44-abce-e0a6a30acfd4/serbia-v-switzerland
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.24fdf8f5-b69b-4341-b6b4-d27605f7f7fd/spain-v-germany
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.c9bdf787-791a-47e0-b77c-a2d4cf567bfd/cameroon-v-serbia
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.5eddaa44-666b-47dc-8a0f-4ac758de00dc/south-korea-v-ghana
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.70cefd39-60f7-415e-9cb5-7a56acd403d6/brazil-v-switzerland
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.7fe0285e-366f-4f3c-b77f-4c96077a6c71/portugal-v-uruguay
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.24fdf8f5-b69b-4341-b6b4-d27605f7f7fd/spain-v-germany
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/rugby-union/france-top-14/group_a.ad22f34f-9cd6-47b4-a826-0c0f0dce7df2/lyon-v-toulouse
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.24fdf8f5-b69b-4341-b6b4-d27605f7f7fd/spain-v-germany
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/rugby-union/france-top-14/group_a.ad22f34f-9cd6-47b4-a826-0c0f0dce7df2/lyon-v-toulouse
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.c9bdf787-791a-47e0-b77c-a2d4cf567bfd/cameroon-v-serbia
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.5eddaa44-666b-47dc-8a0f-4ac758de00dc/south-korea-v-ghana
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.70cefd39-60f7-415e-9cb5-7a56acd403d6/brazil-v-switzerland
https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a.7fe0285e-366f-4f3c-b77f-4c96077a6c71/portugal-v-uruguay
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of collecting all `a` elements on the page where will be a lot of irrelevant results you can use more precise locator.
So, instead of

```py
driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
```

Use this:

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a')]")
```

This will give you desired elements only.
And this

```py
links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a')]")]
```

will directly give you the wanted links only.
**UPD**
In case this is giving you an empty list you possibly are missing a delay. So, you can simply add some pause before that line, like `time.sleep(2)` but it's better to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits for that.
I can't check it since my computer is blocking that link due to my company policy since that is a gambling site, but normally something like this should work:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/football/international-world-cup/group_a')]")))]
```

Comment: thanks, its definately the right way to go about it. It seems I am getting empty lists so need to find out why

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I'm absolutely not familiar with it

Comment: The message is TimeoutException, pretty strange whats happening there.

Comment: maybe there is an iframe there? Can you check that?

Comment: ive edited the question to show the structure of the target, there isnt iframes that are linked to the href